# What are the list workflow approval field values in a REST call?

Tags: workflow, rest, approval-process

I looked at the REST call for a list and noticed that the value for approval was

```
<d:approval m:type="Edm.Int32">16</d:approval>
```

for 'Approved' and

```
 <d:approval m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:approval>
```

for 'In Progress'

What are the other values for the approval field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- NotStarted = 0
- FailedOnStart = 1
- InProgress = 2
- ErrorOccurred = 3
- StoppedByUser = 4
- Completed = 5
- FailedOnStartRetrying = 6
- ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7
- ViewQueryOverflow = 8
- Canceled = 15
- Approved = 16
- Rejected = 17

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowstatus.aspx